# How to convert mongoDB objectID to string in python

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

I am reading in data from mongoDB to pandas dataframe..

```
client = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db = client.test_insert                     ## name of the database
collection = db.dataset2 

df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.dataset2.find()))
```

This will all the documents from dataset2 collection of mongoDB.. Then I am converting it to pandas data frame. 
Next I am storing last inserted objectID of document inserted..

```
last_inserted_id = df['_id'].tail(1)
```

Then I want to read in only new documents inserted in dataset2 collection.. I am trying to do it like this.

```
df2 = db.dataset2.find({"_id": {"$gt": ObjectId(last_inserted_id) }})
```

But it gives me an error

```
TypeError: id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId), not <class       
'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I converted data frames '_id' column into string but it doesn't work.. Gives me the same error.. 
How to do it? please help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this change to the call that throws the error?

```
df2 = db.dataset2.find({"_id": {"$gt": last_inserted_id }})
```

It seems like that's what you're trying to do. The `last_inserted_id` is the value to search; the `ObjectId` is a class, not a valid argument for that mongo find.

Comment: I am facing some new problem whenever I run `last_inserted_id = df['_id'].tail(1)`  I get  `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` What's that? I never came across such a error previously..

Comment: Glad to hear the first solution worked. I think that new one might be best served as a new question - it's not clear to me why that error would arise!

Comment: Your solution giving me an error.. `InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 8    566677507d635d413a2cdd1b
Name: _id, dtype: object` Its not able to convert it into objectId.. That's what it suppose to do so, that it can find documents greater than given objectId. Sorry I thought it was working

Comment: Any solution to above problem?